# Does few long lines of code improve performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a Javascript code for my webpage in a separate file that is going to be quite long and therefore want to clarify my point.

I have come across a number of Javascript libraries, including jQuery, that have code written out in just a few lines. Their code is jumbled up and not written somewhat like this:

```
function someFunc() {
    //some code
}
function anotherFunc() {
    //more code
}
```

Does doing this improve performance? If not then why do the developers do so?

Comment: It's called *minification* and it's done to reduce the size of the source file.

Comment: It's called minification. It makes the filesize smaller simply from containing less bytes. It does not affect performance of the JS, but simply makes the page quicker to load

Comment: Is there any software out there to break the code into blocks for more readability?

Comment: Not reliably. There's plenty of tools to format the code, but the variable names will still be nonsensical and hard to follow. If it's a public library there should be a non-minified version of it for you to download.

Comment: Depends on how much minification was done as to how readable it can be made but there are code beautifier tools for example: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: There are "beautifiers" that attempt to make the code more readable, but really all they can do is format the lines/tabs. If it's been properly minified, the beautified version will still have a bunch of nonsensical shortened variable/method names and be pretty hard to understand.

Comment: Just download the unminified version, if it's available, if you want to read it.